# Parameterized method call in <ui:include> with variable number of method parameters

Tags: jsf-2, el, facelets, param, uiinclude

I have a template that's part of a form to edit some element. The action to be performed is different depending on the page in which it is included. So I pass the action method as a parameter:

```
 <ui:param name="option" value="#{someOptionBean}" />
 ...
 <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/jsf/value-edit.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="controllerParam" value="#{optionController}" />
    <ui:param name="elementParam" value="#{option}" />
    <ui:param name="actionParam" value="updateOption" />
 </ui:include>
```

or:

```
 <ui:param name="property" value="#{somePropertyBean}" />
 ...
 <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/jsf/value-edit.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="controllerParam" value="#{propertyController}" />
    <ui:param name="elementParam" value="#{property}" />
    <ui:param name="actionParam" value="updateProperty" />
 </ui:include>
```

and in `value-edit.xhtml` there is a command button:

```
<p:commandButton value="Update" action="#{controllerParam[actionParam](elementParam)}" />
```

So far everything works fine.

My problem is that now the action methods don't have the same number of parameters. They are:

```
public void updateOption(Option option) { ... }
public void updateProperty(Item item, Prop property) { ... }
```

so I now want to be able to also define the action parameters to have something like:

```
<ui:param name="actionParam" value="updateOption(option)" />
<ui:param name="actionParam" value="updateProperty(item, property)" />
```

or something like:

```
<ui:param name="method" value="updateProperty" />
<ui:param name="parameters" value="item, property" />
```

I've read the docs ([Value and Method Expressions / Parameterized Method Calls](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html#gjhbz)) and I'm not sure if this is possible.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I solved this creating a [`MethodExpression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/MethodExpression.html) in the controller

Now the `ui:include` looks like:

```
<ui:param name="option" value="#{someOptionBean}" />
...
<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/jsf/value-edit.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="actionParam" value="#{optionController.getUpdateAction()}" />
</ui:include>
```

and

```
<ui:param name="item" value="#{someItemBean}" />
<ui:param name="property" value="#{somePropertyBean}" />
...
<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/jsf/value-edit.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="actionParam" value="#{propertyController.getUpdateAction()}" />
</ui:include>
```

In `value-edit.xhtml` the command button is:

```
<p:commandButton value="Update" action="#{actionParam}" />
```

The `getUpdateAction` creates the `MethodExpression` with the corresponding parameters for each controller:

```
public class OptionController {
    ...
    public void updateOption(Option option) { ... } 

    public MethodExpression getUpdateAction() {
        return createMethodExpression("#{optionController.updateOption(option)}", String.class, Option.class);
    }
    ...
}

public class PropertyController {
    ...
    public void updateProperty(Item item, Prop property) { ... }

    public MethodExpression getUpdateAction() {
        return createMethodExpression("#{propertyController.updateProperty(item, property)}", String.class, Item.class, Prop.class);
    }
    ...
}
```

where `createMethodExpression` is:

```
public static MethodExpression createMethodExpression(String expression, Class<?> expectedReturnType, Class<?>... expectedParameterTypes) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(
        facesContext.getELContext(), expression, expectedReturnType, expectedParameterTypes);
}
```